# Form throws error when submitting in PHP to email

Tags: php, html, email

My form throws an error in PHP when submitting form data via email. Not sure what I did wrong/am missing.

Form:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <form id="msform" action="submit.php" method="post" data-autosubmit>
            <!-- Step 1 -->
            <fieldset>
              <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
              <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us about your device.</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" required>
                  <option value="" selected data-default>- Device Brand -</option>
                  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                  <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model">Model</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="model" name="model" required>
                  <option value="" selected data-default>- Device Model -</option>
                  <option value="iPhone 8">iPhone 8</option>
                  <option value="iPhone X">iPhone X</option>
                  <option value="Galaxy S8">Galaxy S8</option>
                  <option valaue="Galaxy S9">Galaxy S9</option>
                  <option value="Galaxy S10">Galaxy S10</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="variant">Storage</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="variant" name="variant" required>
                  <option value="" selected data-default>- Storage Size -</option>
                  <option value="iPhone 8 - 64GB">iPhone 8 - 64GB</option>
                  <option value="iPhone 8 - 256GB">iPhone 8 - 256GB</option>
                  <option value="iPhone X - 64GB">iPhone X - 64GB</option>
                  <option value="iPhone X - 256GB">iPhone X - 256GB</option>
                  <option value="Galaxy S8 - 64GB">Galaxy S8 - 64GB</option>
                  <option valaue="Galaxy S9 - 64GB">Galaxy S9 - 64GB</option>
                  <option value="Galaxy S10 - 128GB">Galaxy S10 - 128GB</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
            </fieldset>
            <!--Step 1 End-->

            <!--Step 2-->
            <fieldset>
              <h2 class="fs-title">Step 2</h2>
              <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Now we need to know more about your device's condition.</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="screen">How is your device's <b>screen</b>?</label>
                <select class="image-picker form-control" id="screen" name="screen" required>
                  <option value="0" data-img-src="">Flawless, no scratches!</option>
                  <option value="1" data-img-src="">1-2 light scratches</option>
                  <option value="2" data-img-src="">3 or more scratches</option>
                  <option value="3" data-img-src="">Cracked or damaged</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">How is your device's <b>housing</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="body" name="body" required>
                  <option value="0">Flawless, no scratches or bends!</option>
                  <option value="1">1-2 light scratches</option>
                  <option value="2">3 or more scratches</option>
                  <option value="3">Bent or severely damaged</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="power">Is your device able to <b>power on</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="power" name="power" required>
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
              <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
            </fieldset>
            <!--Step 2 End-->

            <!--Step 3-->
            <fieldset>
              <h2 class="fs-title">Step 3</h2>
              <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Just a little more information needed, almost there!</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="battery">Does your device have a faulty battery?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="battery" name="battery" required>
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="charge">Is your device able to <b>charge</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="charge" name="charge" required>
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="calls">Is your device able to <b>make and receive calls</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="calls" name="calls">
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fcamera">Does your <b>front camera work</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="fcamera" name="fcamera">
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rcamera">Does your <b>rear camera work</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="rcamera" name="rcamera">
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="water">Is your device <b>water damaged</b>?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="water" name="water">
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="wifi">Is your device able to connect using WiFi?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="wifi" name="wifi">
                  <option value="0">Yes</option>
                  <option value="1">No</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
              <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" onclick="getFinalPrice();" />
            </fieldset>
            <!--End Step 3-->

            <!--Final-->
            <fieldset>
              <h2 class="fs-title">Value</h2>
              <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here's how much we can offer for your device.</h3>
              <h2 id="finalValue"></h2>
              <hr>
              <h3 class="fs-subtitle">If you're happy with our offer, please fill in your contact details below and we'll arrange for free a pickup of your device.</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@example.com" name="email" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="91234567" name="number" required>
                <small id="numberHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email and phone number with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
            <!--Final End-->
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$variant = $_POST['variant'];
$screen = $_POST['screen'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$power = $_POST['power'];
$battery = $_POST['battery'];
$charge = $_POST['charge'];
$calls = $_POST['calls'];
$fcamera = $_POST['fcamera'];
$rcamera = $_POST['rcamera'];
$water = $_POST['water'];
$wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Contact: $number \n Device Brand: $brand \n Device Model: $model \n Device Variant: $variant \n How is your device's screen? $screen \n How is your device's housing? $body \n Is your device able to power on? $power \n Does your device have a fault battery? $battery \n Is your device able to charge? $charge \n Does your front camera work? $fcamera \n Does your rear camera work? $rcamera \n Is your device water damaged? $water \n Is your device able to connect using WiFi? $wifi";
$recipient = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Buyback Request";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank you! We'll be in contact soon. You'll now be redirected back to our main webpage.";
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: https://example.com");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

I gave the input options all a `name` value so that PHP knows where to find the data. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Currently, the form always throws an error on submission.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you know what error it throws?

Comment: You can't use an echo with a header, you'd be outputting before header.

Comment: Is the error is from mail? if yes, have you configured SMTP configuration in your local  host

Comment: @Marty1452 No, how do I find out?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Will remove that line and try again, thanks!

Comment: @Anitha, no its not an SMTP error as previous the mail was posting fine. I added more variables in the PHP script and it broke.